# Formula for the perimeter of an ellipse

Tags: geometry, approximation

So despite being rather amateur when it comes to this level of math, I tried my hand at this and am quite satisfied with the answer.  I've checked the numbers and it's very close to Ramanujan's approximation (never off by more than half of one percent), but I'd really love a second opinion or two.

For semi- axis $a$ and $b$:$$P\approx4b\sqrt[{\large n}]{\frac{a^n}{b^n}+1}; n={\frac{\log(2)}{\log({\frac{\pi}{2}})}}; b\neq0$$
Ramanujan's approximation: $$P_R\approx\pi(a+b)(1+\frac{3h}{10+\sqrt{4-3h}}; h=\frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+b)^2}$$

It is most off when the ratio of a/b is about 5: when a=5 and b=1, $P=21.0861$, and $P_R=21.0100$: a difference of .362%.

Comment: I believe Ramanujan had two approximations formulas. Maybe you can include one, and give a numerical example so we can compare the results?

Comment: A couple of quibbles.  You have only introduced $m$ for the case $a=0$, but this is trivial anyway - so suggest you specify $a,b>0$ and remove $m$. An ellipse is not an elliptic curve, so suggest you change that reference. I guess there should be brackets around $\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: Is there some rationale for that particular value of $n$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind
You are effectively trying to approximate this function.

Comment: This page is probably worth checking out for algebraic approximations: https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/ellipse-perimeter.html

Comment: Combining your approximation and another simple one gives interesting results.

Answer (score 3):

These two are even more accurate (the Pade approximation has a maximum error of .02%):

$$
\text{Ramanujan-Cantrell: Perimeter} = \pi(a+b)\left( 1 + \frac{3h}{10 + \sqrt{4 - 3h}}  + \left( \frac{4}{\pi} - \frac{14}{11} \right) h^{12}\right)
$$

Finally we have a rational function approximation known as a Padé approximation (named after French mathematician Henri Padé).

$$
\text{3rd Padé Approximation: Perimeter } =\pi(a+b)\left( \frac{135168 - 85760h - 5568h^2 + 3867h^3}{135168 - 119552h + 22208h^2 - 345h^3} \right)
$$

Comment: Ramanujan-Cantrell has a maximum error of .015%

Comment: Those errors are relative to the true perimeter, not the Ramanujan II approximation.

Comment: please do not post images as answers

Answer (score 3):

Let $b=k\,a$ and you want to write
$$E\left(1-k^2\right)\sim k \left(1+\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ Using Taylor series around $k=1$
$$E\left(1-k^2\right)=\frac{\pi }{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}  (k-1)+O\left((k-1)^2\right)$$
$$k \left(1+\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=2^{\frac{1}{n}}+ 2^{\frac{1}{n}-1}(k-1)+O\left((k-1)^2\right)$$ Comparing the constant term gives
$$2^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{\pi }{2} \quad \implies \quad n=\frac{\log (2)}{\log \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)} $$ which is your formula.

Using the next term of the series
$$\text{lhs - rhs}=\frac{\pi  \log \left(\frac{\pi ^3}{32}\right)}{32 \log\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)}(1-k)^2\sim -\frac{(1-k)^2}{146} $$

Making the model a bit more complex
$$E\left(1-k^2\right)\sim k \left(1+\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{m}}$$ the same procedure gives $\large (!!)$
$m=n$; so, apparently, no way to improve this kind of formula (which is good).

The maximum absolute error is $0.0038$ and the maximum relative error is $0.362$% (as you wrote it).

Concerning the norm
$$\Phi_1=\int_0^1 \Big(E(1-k^2)- \text{approximation}\Big)^2\,dk =4.956\times 10^{-6}$$

**Edit**

Using
$$E\left(1-k^2\right)\sim k \left(a+\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{m}}$$ it *seems* that the model could be improved using
$$a=\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^m-1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad n=\frac {m\, \pi^m}{2^{m+1} }$$ $m$ being the implicit solution of
$$2 m \left(\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^m-1\right)=3\qquad \qquad m\sim \frac{17}{13-\sqrt[3]{6}}$$ the absolute error on $m$ being $4.65\times 10^{-8}$.

Using

$$\text{lhs - rhs}\sim \frac{(k-1)^3 }{1000}$$

**Update**

I do not remember where I saw the simple approximation
$$E\left(1-k^2\right)\sim \frac{k \pi}{k+1} \csc \left(\frac{k \pi }{k+1}\right)$$ for which the maximum absolute error is $0.0034$ and the maximum relative error is $0.316$% (these are very similar to tour numbers).

Similarly
$$\Phi_2=\int_0^1 \Big(E(1-k^2)- \text{approximation}\Big)^2\,dk =3.818\times 10^{-6}$$

But, what is amazing is that the errors are of opposite sign and the average
$$E\left(1-k^2\right)\sim \frac 12\Bigg(  k \left(1+\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}+ \frac{k \pi}{k+1} \csc \left(\frac{k \pi }{k+1}\right)\Bigg)$$ seems to be interesting since the maximum absolute error becomes $0.00033$

$$\Phi_3=\int_0^1 \Big(E(1-k^2)- \text{approximation}\Big)^2\,dk =2.321\times 10^{-8}$$

$$\text{lhs - rhs}\sim -\frac{(k-1)^2 }{4372}$$